# ssh error: connection timeout to aws ec2 micro instance

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am having trouble connecting to aws ec2 instance.
Here are the details.

**Instance Details**

```
AMI: ubuntu/images/ebs/ubuntu-quantal-12.10-amd64-server-20121218 (ami-422ea672)
Zone: us-west-2b
Security Groups: dev. view rules
Type: t1.micro
```

**Security Group**

```
Ports    Protocol     Source    
0-65535     tcp          0.0.0.0/0  
0-65535     udp          0.0.0.0/0  
-1          icmp         0.0.0.0/0  
22          tcp          106.76.139.164/32
```

I have also added my local ip range in inbound tcp rules for ssh.

**Error Message**

```
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
    debug1: Connecting to ec2-54-245-168-248.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [54.245.168.248] port 22.
    debug1: connect to address 54.245.168.248 port 22: Connection timed out
    ssh: connect to host ec2-54-245-168-248.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

I can successfully ping the instance.
I have initiated ssh connection before on my older account and I faced no problems.

** Things that I have already tried **

- Terminating and Creating a new instance. Didn't work!
- Opening all TCP, UDP, ICMP connections.  Didn't work!
- Associating an elastic IP and using Elastic IP for connection. Didn't work.
- Deleted ssh config file. Didn't work.

Comment: is 106.76.139.164 still your ip address?

Comment: i change it to my current ip every time i try to connect.

Comment: The error indicates that you are not getting a response from the instance. Which often means 1. bad security group settings. 2. Connecting to the wrong ip address. 3. In some cases the instance was unable to boot.

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem due to the fact that my ISP had given me a new IP, with the effect that the Security Group settings for ssh access to my instance being outdating. Updating the allowed IPs in the Security Group to reflect this change fixed the issue.

Comment: Now that I use VPN for everything, my IP changes so this was my problem too. It's an easy fix using "Security Groups" in AWS once you reminded me that I restricted SSH access to a specific network or address.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry. It is because of my ISP.

Comment: what did your isp do? how did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I figured out that it was because the rules related to my security group was not allowing me to SSH to my instance.
For solving this problem:

1. log into your aws account and select **EC2** from **services**.
2. from the left-side column, under security and network, select **security group.**
3. Click on "**Action**" > select "**Edit Inbound Rules**"

[image]

4. for "**Type**" select *SSH* and for "**Source**" select *anywhere*. (leave other things as is)
5. save and go to edit "outbound rules" and do exactly the same steps.

You should be fine now to SSH to your instance!